# Ruby on Rails - Passing values to a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, link-to, url-parameters

I'm a RoR beginner and am using Rails 3.2.3.

I have a search form on my page and it performs a get request and filters the results correctly.

I want to add the possibility of also searching Products by dates.
I inserted a date_select and am able select the date and when the page refreshes after the search, the chosen dates are still there on the date_select, as I am able to get them through `params`.

However, my issue is that when the page renders the products, they have a link_to to their show action.
My goal is to also pass alongside the url the dates that were selected to perform the search on that link_to.

For ex, if the user selects a date of 20-06-2012 to 25-06-2012 it only shows products inserted on that time frame (and all those params are on the url)

But the link to show action of each displayed product is only:

```
link_to <%= link_to product.name, product%>
```

which renders

`http://localhost:3000/products/24` (por example)

what I want to render/show is something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/24?from=20-06-2012&to=25-06-2012
```

The selected dates to perform the search are not stored in the database at this moment, but I will need to get them from the URL on a latter page, therefore, both dates will need to be preserved through 2 different pages before the users fills a form and then those dates are inserted in the DB.

Any tips on this? I've searched but all I found was on how to pass variables that exist in the model and I do not want to use cookies nor session variables.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass arbitrary parameters to the following call

```
<%= link_to product.name, product %>
```

you need to invoke the path method explicitly instead of using the implicit version. The line above is equivalent to

```
<%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %>
```

Then you can pass parameters

```
<%= link_to product.name, product_path(product, :from => 'whatever', :to => 'whatever') %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try like this

```
link_to <%= link_to product.name, product, :param_you_want => "value you want" %>
```

Now you can set value in "param_you_want" as you wish.

But in my case set value in it "value you want"

Hope you can get idea

Comment: I tried and it doesn't render a link with the `"value you want"` in front of it nor does the show page have it in its parameters when loaded (I checked usign `params`, it o nly has this: `{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"products", "id"=>"24"}`. Any tips?

Comment: @ali with your example the parameters are passed as `html_options` to the link helper, not path parameters. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to